# Why do I get incorrect timestamp on mounted file system on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, timestamp, mount

I have created a cramfile using mkfs.cramfs utility and mounted the cramfile on a directory,

file1.txt were freshly created and timestamps were verified.

mkfs.cramfs testdir testcram.cram

mount -o loop testcram.cram temporarydir

when I view the permission of the files in temporarydir by `ls -la` I get below details

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 woi 232 0 1970-01-01 05:30 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 woi 232 0 1970-01-01 05:30 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 woi 232 0 1970-01-01 05:30 file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 woi 232 0 1970-01-01 05:30 file4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 woi 232 0 1970-01-01 05:30 file5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 woi 232 0 1970-01-01 05:30 file6.txt
```

Wanted to the reason why it is displaying such incorrect timestamp.

Comment: What date do you get if you type `date`?

Comment: Thu Oct 17 15:41:12 IST 2013 Which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> No timestamps are stored in a cramfs, so these default to the epoch
>   (1970 GMT).  Recently-accessed files may have updated timestamps, but
>   the update lasts only as long as the inode is cached in memory, after
>   which the timestamp reverts to 1970, i.e. moves backwards in time.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/cramfs.txt

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the reason the files were showing outdated timestamp, the files were mounted automatically by the machine, and had read only permission, since it was mounted file system, it seems all the mounted file systems show 1970 timestamp. I tried manually mounting a folder on my local machine.